# PL/SQL String Validation

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to write a script that prompts for a input and it should validate if the given input has 19 characters;the first 3 characters must be 'ABC' followed by 16 characters(combination of alphabets and numbers)...

```
def mch_id='&1'

declare
chk_var varchar2(200) := '&mch_id';
begin
   IF chk_var like'ABC_____________' then
        dbms_output.put_line('correct');
   else
        dbms_output.put_line('incorrect');
   end if;
end;
```

Expected Output :

```
ABC5678GVTC438755RW43 - correct 
ADSE4NJ8GGFT5FVNOKNHY - incorrect
```

Comment: The code seems to write out either 'correct' or 'incorrect' - how can the Expected Output be either of the strings you show below the code? Please clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison string is only 16 characters long, ABC and 13 underscores. You need 16 underscores to follow ABC according to your specification.

EDIT:  As HepC notes below, even after fixing the number of underscores, you may still get incorrect answers. This is because the underscore stands for ANY character, not only for alpha or numeric.

Try this instead:

```
... if regexp_like(chk_var, '^ABC[[:alnum:]]{16}$') then...
```

This evaluates as TRUE if and only if chk_var matches

- from the beginning of the string (the ^ marker)
- the letters A, B, C in order
- any alpha or numeric character (the outer [...] means any single character in the list provided within [...]; inside it, [:alnum:] is shorthand for any alpha or numeric character)
- exactly 16 occurrences of "a single alnum character" (the 16 characters may be different from each other) (the {16} marker)
- and the end of the string right after that (the $ marker).

Sample SQL*Plus session (screenshot):

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> define mch_id = 'ABC1234567812345678'
SQL> declare
  2  chk_var varchar2(200) := '&mch_id';
  3  begin
  4     if regexp_like(chk_var, '^ABC[[:alnum:]]{16}$') then
  5          dbms_output.put_line('correct');
  6     else
  7          dbms_output.put_line('incorrect');
  8     end if;
  9  end;
 10  /
old   2: chk_var varchar2(200) := '&mch_id';
new   2: chk_var varchar2(200) := 'ABC1234567812345678';
correct

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> define mch_id = 'ABC123456781234%%%%'
SQL> /
old   2: chk_var varchar2(200) := '&mch_id';
new   2: chk_var varchar2(200) := 'ABC123456781234%%%%';
incorrect

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: This is a good oberservation. However, if the trailing 16 characters need to be alphanumeric then expanding the `LIKE` comparison is still insufficient. You might consider writing a simple regular expression instead.

Comment: err... right, I only pointed out what was wrong in the code provided, but didn't think about what ELSE may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am still not getting the expected result.. However,there is no error but it's just printing out infinite numbers.

Comment: Not sure why you are not getting the expected result. Is that ALL the code you are running? I am adding a screenshot of my SQL\*Plus session where everything seems to work perfectly fine. How are you running the code? (What front-end, are you calling it from another app, etc.)